# Deallocating MPI window that provides shared memory access without performing a barrier synchronization

Tags: python, c++, garbage-collection, mpi, mpich

I want to deallocate MPI shared memory, but using "MPI_Win_free" to free the memory window and the attached shared memory requires a barrier synchronization inside "MPI_Win_free".

The barrier synchronization means that the processes will wait on each other. That is problematic if you have to implement a destructor for a C++ object that manages the shared memory and use it in python where garbage collection of such an object then can cause that some MPI process are waiting to deallocate the shared memory while others may already be waiting in some collective call. Hence the program will hang.

An example of allocating and deallocating MPI shared memory:

```
    int world_rank;
    MPI_Comm_rank (MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_rank);

    MPI_Comm communicator;
    MPI_Comm_split_type(
        MPI_COMM_WORLD,
        MPI_COMM_TYPE_SHARED,
        world_rank,
        MPI_INFO_NULL,
        &communicator);

    MPI_Info window_info;
    MPI_Info_create(&window_info);
    MPI_Info_set(window_info, "no_locks", "true");

    double * local_allocated_mem_ptr;

    MPI_Win shared_mem_win;

    // The master process of the communicator should allocate all the
    // shared memory.
    if (world_rank == 0)
    {
        int const size = 5;
        MPI_Aint local_allocated_mem_size = size * sizeof(double);
        MPI_Win_allocate_shared(
           local_allocated_mem_size,
           sizeof(double),
           window_info,
           communicator,
           &local_allocated_mem_ptr,
           &shared_mem_win);
    }
    else
    {
        MPI_Aint local_allocated_mem_size = 0;
        MPI_Win_allocate_shared(
            local_allocated_mem_size,
            sizeof(double),
            window_info,
            communicator,
            &local_allocated_mem_ptr,
            &shared_mem_win);
    }

    MPI_Info_free(&window_info);

    // Deallocate the shared memory again.
    // The MPI_Win_free function includes a synchronization barrier that I want to skip.
    MPI_Win_free(&shared_mem_win);
```

According to the documentation one "may" avoid the barrier synchronization in "MPI_Win_free" by setting the MPI_Info key 'no_locks' to 'true' as described here:

https://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-3.1/mpi31-report/node265.htm

> MPI_WIN_FREE requires a barrier synchronization: no process can return from free until all processes in the group of win call free. This ensures that no process will attempt to access a remote window (e.g., with lock/unlock) after it was freed. The only exception to this rule is when the user sets the no_locks info key to true when creating the window. In that case, an MPI implementation may free the local window without barrier synchronization.

and here:

https://books.google.de/books?id=Po5IBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA95&lpg=PA95&dq=MPI_Info_set+%22no_locks%22&source=bl&ots=Da5hS0HIRg&sig=ACfU3U0SzRto57L4XL41fiO1Db3Pzg2Ctw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwivzpKeusLqAhVVwMQBHSNPCMgQ6AEwAHoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=MPI_Info_set%20%22no_locks%22&f=false

The example above also shows this approach, but it has no effect since there still is a barrier. So is there an alternative way of freeing shared memory that is guaranteed to have no barrier synchronization?

Comment: The MPI standard does **not** mandate `no_locks` makes `MPI_Win_free()` barrier-less. If you are fine with writing non portable code, you'd rather check other MPI implementations and see if they meet your expectations.

Comment: An ```MPI_Win``` is not shared memory. It's a Remote Memory Access (RMA) window, i.e. allows other ranks to access remote memory.
Just saying that, because when I read the question title, I didn't know what you were referring to, but then in the question text, it became clear. So you might want to change that wording. "Window" or "MPI_Win" should be clear in an MPI context.

Comment: @RL-S Hope the title is a little more clear now. Thank you.

Comment: Sounds more like you have a problem with your object lifetimes. If freeing the window is a problem, put it in a queue or something for deferred freeing.